# How can we define complex type for a stored procedure that accepts dynamic query as input [edmx]

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, edmx

I have a stored procedure like this

```
create proc usp_ProjectName_DBQuery
    @strDBQuery varchar(8000)
as
begin
   exec (@strDBQuery)
end
```

So this will accept any DBQuery and it will execute it in the server.

Now my problem is this will return n number of columns based on the query.

For example if I pass in `select x,y from db` it will return two columns, but if i pass in `select * from db` it will return n columns, it sometimes may not return anything

So how can I define a complex type for this stored procedure!? Please help

Comment: You cannot - period. You cannot have stored procedures that return varying shapes of responses in EF - you just plain cannot. If you must have this setup (really bad design smell in my opinion), then you have to deal with basic ADO.NET

Comment: Even worse, this is SQL Injection in its purest form.  Unless the only users of this will be DBA's and sysadmins, it's a security nightmare waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@marc_s is right this is not something you can do in EF (without third party library).
Entity framework doesn't really like that.
You have 2 options:

1. Use ADO.NET instead as suggested in the comments
2. Change your stored procedure to return the same number of column even of they are empty fields.

Comment: Ok @Meda Thank you ! 
If i go with basic ADO.NET then I have to do all things that are done by EF manually rigth?! I mean creating class, complex types etc?!

Comment: @vignesh yes exactly , which will require a lot more code then EF but thats outweighted outweighted by its flexibilty